# Flotilla not working on Rasbian Pixel and Buster

Tags: python, raspbian

I recently order a Flottila Dock and three modules to attach to it. I would like to use it with python but it’s very challenging :( Trying to run the following code gives me the error

```
AttributeError: ‘module’ object has no attribute ‘Client’
```

```
import flotilla
dock = flotilla.Client()
dock.ready
```

These are the steps i’ve followed:

I initially tried to install it on a Rasbian Buster and after many attempts i managed to clone the flottila-python library. The `curl -sS https://get.pimoroni.com/flotilla | bash` command was giving me an error that this version is not supported. I applied the solutions suggested here Flotilla installer not working on "buster" but without any luck.

I then installed it on Rasbian Pixel and everything went smooth. However, when i try to run the code i get the same error.

Any hint on how to solve this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Some hack from Pimoroni Support:

```
git clone https://github.com/pimoroni/flotilla-offline
cd flotilla-offline
```

​And then editing the install.sh file so that the line that currently reads:

```
case “$RELEASE” in
“9.0” | “9.1” | “9.2” | “9.3” | “9.4” | “9.5” | “9.6” | “9.7” | “9.8” | “9.9”)
```

is changed to

```
case “$RELEASE” in
“9.0” | “9.1” | “9.2” | “9.3” | “9.4” | “9.5” | “9.6” | “9.7” | “9.8” | “9.9” | “10”)
```

You can then run sudo `./install`.

More on [Pimoroni forum](https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/flotilla-installer-not-working-on-buster/11032).